# Implementing Mixed of SSR and CSR in NextJS Similar to Angular Universal

Tags: reactjs, angular, server-side-rendering, next.js13, angular-universal

We have been using Angular Universal for its ability to mix SSR and CSR - rendering the first page on the server and then switching to client-side rendering for subsequent actions. This approach leverages the strengths of both SSR (improved initial load performance and SEO benefits) and CSR (smooth, interactive user experiences).

Recently, we started exploring NextJS for a new project and noticed that its SSR functionality differs from Angular Universal's. In NextJS, it seems that pages are either entirely server-side rendered or client-side rendered, without a mixed approach.

**Our Requirement:** We want the initial page (e.g., a 'find-product' page accessed from a Google search) to be server-side rendered. However, once on the site, if a user navigates to a different page (like a 'product-view' page by clicking on a product card), this navigation should be client-side rendered, with API calls being made to back-end from the browser. Conversely, if a user directly accesses the 'product-view' page, it should be server-side rendered.

We haven't found clear documentation or examples on how to implement this mixed SSR/CSR model in NextJS. Our findings are often conflated with other rendering strategies like pre-rendering and Static Site Generation (SSG).

**Question:** Is there a way to implement a mixed SSR/CSR approach in NextJS similar to what we have experienced with Angular Universal? If so, how can it be achieved? We are relatively new to NextJS, so any guidance or references to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

We tried app router and page router-based server-side rendering with next js but all pages are getting rendered on server side only and it doesn't work as client-side rendering for sub sequent actions.